# is Android DHCP server when tethering?

Tags: cyanogenmod, tethering

I am on cyanogenmod 7 and wonder when I do usb tethering if Android is DHCP server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Specifically, CyanogenMod uses [Dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) for its DHCP services. You can see it being invoked on [this line in the TetherController.cpp](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_system_netd/blob/gingerbread/TetherController.cpp#L131) file of their source code.