# Does Android USB Shared connection runs a DHCP Server?

Tags: tethering, dhcp

I'm aware of USB Shared connection of android and I've been using it to give connection to my computer.

Also I've an old domestic router which has RJ45 and wireless interfaces. I've been thinking about connecting my phone directly to the router using an USB-RJ45 converter, in order to give internet to the computer based on the RJ45 switched interface of the router, plus some other wireless devices using WiFi.

So my question is: **does Android USB Shared connection runs a DHCP Server?**

Because in case it does, everything will run fine, but if it doesn't, I'm afraid it would only support one device to give it an IP.

I've found that in cyanogenmod [does](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9868/is-android-dhcp-server-when-tethering), but dunno in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Yes. Definitely.

What a DHCP server basically does is not only dynamically allocating IP addresses, but auto-configuring some IP settings as well, for example DNS servicing.

Judging from a client's (let's say, your computer) behavior, it surely runs a DHCP server. If not, you'll have to configure IP settings (static IP) and enter DNS server addresses and Gateway address manually. But you don't have to do these by yourself, so you can confidently infer that a DHCP server is working.

Comment: Makes sense. Was expecting any official doc saying it, but your reasoning is completely valid.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer most probably runs a dhcp client service, which requests an ip address from a dhcp server. In most home networks this is commonly the router, who in turn runs a dhcp request against the dhcp server from your isp.
With that request, also information about the name servers is obtained, which is than often passed on, using the dhcp mechanism to the local network, so clients can contact the external services directly.
In case of tethering, your phone will provide the same functions as your router would, getting ip information from the mobile network through it's dhcp service and provide dhcp services to your Wi-Fi connection.
I've noticed in earlier days, that my computer would sometimes not get an ip address.
In that case, using a fixed ip of 192.168.43.10 (or any other last digit between (2-254) and a netmask of 255.255.255.0, gateway 192.168.43.1 would work